# suppose p(y|theta) is poisson distribution with mean parameter theta. show that the sample mean is an efficient estimator theta.

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

> **(Problem 9.3)** Suppose $p(y \mid \theta)$ is a Poisson distribution with mean parameter $\theta$.  Show that the sample mean is an efficient estimator of $\theta$.

Work shown:

> $$\hat V(\theta) = \frac{1}{n \operatorname{E}[(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \log f(y \mid \theta))^2]}$$
>   $$\begin{align*} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(y \mid \theta) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left[\log \frac{e^{-\theta} \theta^y}{y!} \right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left[ \log e^{-\theta}  \theta^y \frac{1}{y!} \right] \\ 
> &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left[ -\theta + y \log \theta - \log y! \right] \\
> &= -1 + \frac{y}{\theta}. \end{align*} $$

I can do only basic calculus, so I need detailed explanation about this problem.
If you can't describe it smoothly, because of the online environment, please let me know a book(or chapter name) that I can refer to.

q1. Does the symbol before the $\log$ have the same meaning as $d$(differential)?
     * it's very good for me, if you illustrate about this little bit...

q2. I don't know how this equation(note) has proceeded.
    Please explain it to me step-by-step.

q3.  $f(y\mid \theta)$ is Bayes' rule?
     I think it isn't, but if isn't why is it written like that? Also, what is it?!

Thanks you for reading despite my poor grammar.

Comment: I have edited your question to include the proper formatting.  Please take the time to look at how your post was edited so that in the future, you will be able to properly typeset your correspondence on this site.  You can do this by either clicking on the "edit" link to see all of the edits at once, or to right-click on a math equation to see how it was typeset.

Comment: This is my first time to use this website. so i didn't know how to write that down. Did you type that code one by one? use program? or copy and paste?...

Answer (score 1):

Q1.  The symbol $\partial$ refers to *partial* differentiation.  If one has a function of a single variable, for example $$f(x) = x^2,$$ then the first derivative of this function with respect to this single variable would be written as $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)\right] = \frac{df}{dx} = 2x.$$  If one has a function of more than one variable, e.g., $$f(x,y) = x^2 y + y^3 - 12,$$ then we can compute partial derivatives with respect to either $x$ or $y$, and they are written $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[f(x,y)\right] = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xy, \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[f(x,y)\right] = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x^2 + 3y^2.$$  In this case, the reason why we use a partial derivative is because the log-likelihood $\log f(y \mid \theta)$ is a function of $y$ as well as $\theta$.

Q2.  Your question is too broad.  You need to be more specific about what you do not understand about this solution.  Generally, what is being computed here is the **Cramer-Rao lower bound** for the variance of the sample mean of an IID sample $\boldsymbol y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ of size $n$ drawn from a Poisson distribution with unknown mean $\theta$.  Then, if we can show that the variance of the sample mean of this estimator attains this bound, that this estimator is a **UMVUE** (since the sample mean is unbiased).

I should also point out here that the notation that was used above is incorrect:  $\hat V (\theta)$ does not make sense.  Instead, it should read $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat\theta],$$ and the equality after this is not actually an equality, but an inequality; i.e., it should read $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat\theta] \ge \frac{1}{n \operatorname{E}[(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \log f(y \mid \theta))^2]}.$$  This is because you are calculating a lower bound on the variance of the estimator $\hat \theta$ which in this case is the sample mean $\bar y = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$.  You are not calculating an estimate of the variance of a parameter, which is what $\hat V(\theta)$ notates.  A parameter is not a random variable--it has no variance to speak of and no distributional assumption has been applied in this context.

Q3.  $f(y \mid \theta)$ describes the conditional density of a distribution, given the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: what i can't understand is differentiating log part..... $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left[\log \frac{e^{-\theta} \theta^y}{y!} \right $$ and did you just type that all these code? or copy and paste?... this is my first time to use this website...

Comment: @joseya7 The Poisson PMF is $$f(y \mid \theta) = e^{-\theta} \frac{\theta^y}{y!}, \quad y = 0, 1, 2, \ldots.$$  So if we take the logarithm, we get $$\log f(y \mid \theta) = -\theta + y \log \theta - \log y!,$$ and taking the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$ means that we treat $y$ as a constant when differentiating:  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left[f(y \mid \theta)\right] = -1 + \frac{y}{\theta}.$$  Yes, I type this code directly.

Comment: @joseya7 Your comment did not typeset correctly because you are missing a closing bracket symbol `]` after `\right`.

Comment: Why take the logarithm?

Comment: and how can be, log⁡f(y∣θ)=−θ+ylog⁡θ−log⁡y!, ?... I will learn how to do typeset except this time.

Comment: @joseya7 If you do not understand why the logarithm is taken, this indicates you do not have the prerequisite knowledge necessary to understand any explanations of the solution to your question.  You will need to review the proof of the Cramer-Rao lower bound.

Comment: @joseya7 You also do not seem to be aware of the basic rules for logarithms:  $$\log (ab) = \log a + \log b, \quad a, b > 0,$$ and $$\log e^a = a, \quad a \in \mathbb R.$$  This is a serious issue:  if you cannot do basic algebra, you have no hope of making further progress in this area of mathematics, and your question is beyond the scope of your current level of mathematical knowledge.

Comment: No. I know log(ab)= loga + logb and loge^a =a T.T.... But i don't know logf(y∣θ)=−θ+ylogθ−logy!, why this conditional is just like that.... sorry for questioning without specific query...

Comment: If $$f(y \mid \theta) = e^{-\theta} \frac{\theta^y}{y!},$$ then $$\log f(y \mid \theta) = \log \left(e^{-\theta} \theta^y / y! \right) = \log e^{-\theta} + \log \theta^y - \log y! = -\theta + y \log \theta - \log y!.$$  There are no additional intermediate steps in this computation to display, if you are aware of the rules for logarithms.

Comment: Really thanks you for not quitting to answer my poor questioning. I  understand why take the logarithm by finding CRLB proof  as you asked and why logf(y∣θ)=−θ+ylogθ−logy!, is. and also thanks for coding tip. I was really surprised and thankful because answer is so fast and organized.